# SQL fetch is working but not working in trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am trying to create a trigger, before create I try to test it as executing the code inside. The fetch codes are working itself but trigger is not working. Here is the code:

```
USE [PMIDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BRK_ÇEKME_KAP_INSERTED]
ON [dbo].[ATMATERIALTRANS]
FOR INSERT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @RDATE DATE
    DECLARE @MAKİNE VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @OKUTULAN_BARKOD VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @MIKTAR INT
    DECLARE @WC_ID INT
SELECT * FROM ATMATERIALTRANS

DECLARE CUR CURSOR 
FOR 

    SELECT TDATE, WORKCENTERS.CODE, ATMATERIALS.BARCODE, ATMATERIALS.AMOUNT, WC_ID  FROM INSERTED T1     
                                LEFT JOIN ATCOMPOSITIONS ON ATCOMPOSITIONS.ID=T1.COMPID
                                LEFT JOIN WORKCENTERS ON WORKCENTERS.ID=T1.WC_ID
                                LEFT JOIN ATMATERIALS ON ATMATERIALS.ID=ATCOMPOSITIONS.MATERIALID
        WHERE T1.COMPID IS NOT NULL AND WORKCENTERS.CODE LIKE 'DD%'

OPEN CUR 
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @RDATE, @MAKİNE, @OKUTULAN_BARKOD,@MIKTAR, @WC_ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BURAK..ÇEKME_KAP (TARİH,MAKİNE,OKUTULAN_BARKOD,MİKTAR, HAMMADDE_GCKOD)
        VALUES 
        (@RDATE,
        @MAKİNE,
        @OKUTULAN_BARKOD,
        @MIKTAR, 'G')

        UPDATE BURAK..MALKABUL_BARKOD SET BURAK..MALKABUL_BARKOD.KULLANILDI =1 WHERE BURAK..MALKABUL_BARKOD.BARKOD=@OKUTULAN_BARKOD
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @RDATE, @MAKİNE, @OKUTULAN_BARKOD,@MIKTAR, @WC_ID      
END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
END
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: 1. Cursor + trigger is very anti-pattern. 2. You really don't need that cursor that can be replaced by a regular inser and update, 3. Do you really needs it inside a trigger? 4. This smell as a misplaced business rule, cannot it fit better in the business layer?

Comment: How have you determined that it's "not working"?

Comment: 1. I agree with you
2. I agree with you, will try to do without fetch..
3. I really need trigger, inserted time is too important, it should be done exactly at the same time when inserted to original table before some other undependend queries completed.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like you are trying to create a trigger to return result set to the application, which should be avoided.

   2. This SQL statement looks, does not require a cursor at all. This can be achieved by a simple DML statement.

Please refer the statements below, before writing a trigger to return a result to the application via a trigger.

**"When a trigger fires, results are returned to the calling application, just like with stored procedures. To prevent having results returned to an application because of a trigger firing, do not include either SELECT statements that return results or statements that perform variable assignment in a trigger. A trigger that includes either SELECT statements that return results to the user or statements that perform variable assignment requires special handling; these returned results would have to be written into every application in which modifications to the trigger table are allowed. If variable assignment must occur in a trigger, use a SET NOCOUNT statement at the start of the trigger to prevent the return of any result sets."**